# Receiving InvalidCastException when obtaining SystemFirmwareVersion using EasClientDeviceInformation

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, windows-10

I am using the [EasClientDeviceInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.aspx) class to obtain information about the user's device.

Using these two lines

```
EasClientDeviceInformation deviceInfo = new EasClientDeviceInformation();
var version = deviceInfo.SystemFirmwareVersion;
```

generates an `InvalidCastException` on the second line. The full error detail is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation'
>   to type
>   'Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.IEasClientDeviceInformation2

This code is very standard and only leads me to believe that for my system the `SystemFirmwareVersion` might be unobtainable. However, I don't understand why this should necessarily throw a casting exception. Obviously the cast from `EasClientDeviceInformation` to `IEasClientDeviceInformation2` is causing the issue here but that's internal to the `EasClientDeviceInformation` class and not to my own code. Why would this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post is tagged with both `windows-10` and `windows-8.1`, which is confusing.

The `2` interface doesn't exist at all on Windows 8.1 (it was introduced in Windows Phone), so this code will never work on Windows 8.1 desktop machines (and you wouldn't be able to compile the code using default project templates).

The `2` interface does exist in Windows 10, but you might be on an earlier OS build that didn't (yet) have the implementation; suggest you update to the latest build ('162 or higher). That said, I *think* this property always returns an empty string on Desktop.

[Addition 7/10/2015]

The other thing to remember is that because this API doesn't exist across all device families (only Mobile and Desktop), you should use the [`ApiInformation` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.metadata.apiinformation.aspx) to check for the presence of the API before using it on Windows 10. That way, your app won't crash when running on an Xbox or some other device.